# If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then dim$_{x}f^{-1}(f(x)) =0$ for each $x\in X$?

Tags: general-topology

Literally,
If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then dim$_{x}f^{-1}(f(x)) =0$ for each $x\in X$ ?

Here, for a topological space $X$, $\dim_{x}X$ is defined as $\operatorname{inf dim}U$, where $U$ runs through all open neighborhoods of $x$. And for an arbitrary topological space $X$, $\operatorname{dim}X$ is defined as the supremum of all length $X_0 \supsetneq X_1 \supsetneq \cdots \supsetneq X_l $ of irreducilbe closed subsets of $X$.

I guess that it's true and ask for making sure.

My argument is simple : $\operatorname{dim}_{x}f^{-1}(f(x)) = \operatorname{dim}_x(\{x\}) =0$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Since $f$ is a bijection, I note that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $x \in X$.  However, I do not know what your operation $\dim_x$ refers to.

Comment: $\operatorname{dim}_x $ is defined as the infimum of toplogocial dimension of $U$, where $U$ runs through all open neighborhoods of $x$. And the topological dimension of $X$ is defined as the supremum of all length of chains $X_0  \supsetneq X_1 \supsetneq  \cdots \supsetneq X_l$ of irreducible closed subsets of $X$

Comment: You've defined $\mathrm{dim}_x$ (maybe), but what does $\mathrm{dim}_x f^{-1}(f(x))$ mean?

Comment: $\operatorname{dim}_{x}f^{-1}(f(x))$ means the dimension of $f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$ (endowed with the subspace topology from X) at $x$. Any furthur information needed?

Comment: You suggest that $dim_x$ has a definition in terms of $x$, but what does $dim_x[A]$ refer to, and what type of object is $A$ assumed to be?

Comment: There $A$ refers to a topological space containing $x$. And $\operatorname{dim}_{x}A := \operatorname{inf dim}U$ where $U$ runs through all open neighborhoods of $A$ containing $x$.

Comment: You should include these definitions in the body of the question. Comments may disappear.

Comment: O.K. I update an associated definition. Thanks you.

Comment: I found this link about a "Krull dimension" which seems quite different from ordinary notions of dimension: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0054 The use of $f^{-1}(f(x))$ as a "topological space" is confusing since it looks like a function, rather than a set. But also it is clearly the identity function (so why even introduce $f$?). I think $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are red herrings.  It sounds like you are asking: If a single point $x$ is treated as a topological space, is its Krull dimension 0?

Comment: Uhm..more correctly, $f^{-1}(f(x))$ means $f^{-1}\{(f(x)\})$, the preimage of $\{f(x)\}$ under the $f$. And we endow $f^{-1}\{(f(x)\})$ the subspace topology from X